# Change a react component's state on a click of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show/hide a component based on its state and I want to change it on a click in a 3rd component.

//navbar

```
export class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showNotification: false,
    }
  }

  handleNotification = () => this.setState({
    showNotification: !this.state.showNotification,
  });

  { this.state.showNotification ? <Outside><Notifications /></Outside> : null}
```

//outside component, responsible for detect if a click happened outside it.

```
export default class Outside extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
     document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside)
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClickOutside(event) {
    if(this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("clicked outside notifications");
      this.setState({
        showNotification: false
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
         {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Outside.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

My doubt is how can I change the state in navbar based on the event that is being detected inside `Outside component` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parent, you need downward to Outside a event handler:

```
<Outside toggleNofitication={this.handleNotification}><Notifications /></Outside>
```

and in Outside, just call `toggleNofitication` when event fired:

```
handleClickOutside = () => {
    // ...
    this.props.toggleNofitication()
}
```

Comment: do you have an example ? its throwing a error "this.props.toggleNotification is not a function at Outside"

Comment: oh sory, my mistake. Pass `toggleNofitication` to `Outside` instead of `Notifications`. See my updated aswer